# The ability to control Spotify specific notifications from the Ubuntu 20.04 desktop's notifications settings are missing

Tags: gnome, 20.04, notification, spotify

Is there a fix for the notification controls missing from the setting for Spotify? Need to stop just pop-ups, **not** all the notifications.

- OS: Ubuntu 20.04
- Spotify version: 1.1.26.501.gbe11e53b-15 (latest/stable)
- Source: Snap

Notification settings looks like this:

[image: Notification settings looks like this]

Comment: I use Spotify's deb package instead of snap package. There's a option in settings as **Show Desktop notifications when song changes** under **Display Options**. It disables pop-up notifications but still shows song currently being played in notification bar. Does this achieve what you looking for?

Comment: Thanks for the response. But it didn't do what I'm looking for. This worked without a hassle on Ubuntu 18.04. I did a fresh installation of 20.04. The problem appeared after that.